# Nested Strategy Design Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unity-game-engine

Suppose we have a player which controls a character named Player1. To enable switching weapons at runtime, I have the following code:

```
public interface IWeapon
{
    void Fire();
}

public class Player1Weapon1 : IWeapon
{
    ...
    void Fire()
    {
        //do actions of Weapon1
    }
    ...
}

public class Player1Weapon2 : IWeapon
{
    ...
    void Fire()
    {
        //do actions of Weapon2
    }
    ...
}

public class Player1
{
    IWeapon weapon;
    Player1Weapon1 w1;
    Player1Weapon2 w2;

    public Player1() 
    { 
        w1 = new  Player1Weapon1(this);
        w2 = new  Player1Weapon2(this);
        SetWeapon(w1);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if(SWITCH_BTN_HELD)
        {
            if(weapon.equals(w1))  SetWeapon(w2);
            if(weapon.equals(w2))  SetWeapon(w1);
        }
        if(FIRE_BTN_HELD)
            weapon.Fire();
    }
    void SetWeapon(w)
    {
        weapon = w;
    }
}
```

That works perfectly.

But now a player can select another character named Player2.
Note that Player2's Weapons are different from Player1. So we can add Classes like this:

```
public class Player2Weapon1 : IWeapon
{
    ...
    void Fire()
    {
        //do actions of Weapon1
    }
    ...
}
public class Player2Weapon2 : IWeapon
{
    ...
    void Fire()
    {
        //do actions of Weapon2
    }
    ...
}

public class Player2
{
    IWeapon weapon;
    Player2Weapon1 w1;
    Player2Weapon2 w2;

    public Player2() 
    { 
        w1 = new  Player2Weapon1(this);
        w2 =new  Player2Weapon2(this);
        SetWeapon(w1);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if(SWITCH_BTN_HELD)
        {
        if(weapon.equals(w1))  SetWeapon(w2);
        if(weapon.equals(w2))  SetWeapon(w1);
        }
        if(FIRE_BTN_HELD)
        weapon.Fire();
    }
    void SetWeapon(w)
    {
        weapon=w;
    }
}
```

It will work again but it is very tight, if a player wants to play with Player3, I should addmore classes to the project .

I am wondering how to make Strategy Pattern for flayers like below:

```
interface IPlayer()
{

}
```

I don't know which methods will be placed in IPlayer? How can I create nested Strategy Design Patterns?

Comment: I think your players shouldn't even have "PlayerXWeapon", just an IEnumerable of IWeapons.

Comment: Yes don't name an item after the player who will use it.  Imagine if your game allowed one player to drop the weapon and the other player picked it up.  That would be confusing.  The weapon can exist independent of the person who could hold it.

Comment: @MickyDuncan , yes but what is the solution ?

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid, by implementing one Player class that delegates the Fire() operation to one of different Weapon classes. Which weapon to use can be specified and changed dynamically. See my UML diagrams below.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if I get what you are asking or if you don't know how/what to ask. Strategy pattern is not what you need the most here. I try to give my two cents.

First of all, I don't think it's a good idea to have concrete classes in your players, like `Player1Weapon`. It should only contain `IWeapon`s. This way you don't need to specifically define which weapons your players use nor create new player classes for every variations.

Consider the following. You have these `IWeapons` in `SomeNamespace` namespace.

```
public interface IWeapon
{
    void Fire();
}

public class Shotgun : IWeapon
{
    public void Fire()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Shotgun goes boom");
    }
}

public class Knife : IWeapon
{
    public void Fire()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stabbed teh sucker");
    }
}

public class NuclearBomb : IWeapon
{
    public void Fire()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Game over for everyone!!1");
    }
}
```

Now your `Player` class could look like below. Just add any level of abstraction you might need, here I just assume you don't.

```
public class Player
{
    private IWeapon _wielded;

    public Player(string name)
        :this(name, null, null)
    {}

    public Player(string name, IWeapon primary, IWeapon secondary)
    {
        Name = name;
        Primary = _wielded = primary;
        Secondary = secondary;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Player '{0}' spawned", Name));
    }

    public void Switch()
    {
        _wielded = _wielded != Primary ? Primary : Secondary;
    }

    public void Fire()
    {
        if (_wielded != null)
            _wielded.Fire();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IWeapon Primary { get; set; }

    public IWeapon Secondary { get; set; }
}
```

To create "any player" you could have a simple factory to "spawn" them taking required attributes as parameter.

```
public class PlayerFactory
{
    // key = player name, value = weapons
    public Player Create(KeyValuePair<string, string[]> args)
    {
        var primary = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(args.Value[0])) as IWeapon;
        var secondary = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(args.Value[1])) as IWeapon;

        var player = new Player(args.Key, primary, secondary);
        return player;
    }
}
```

And now if you run the below "initialization"...

```
// this would come from config file or similar
var config = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string,string[]>(
            "Player1", new[] { "SomeNamespace.Shotgun", "SomeNamespace.Knife" }),
        new KeyValuePair<string,string[]>(
            "Player2", new[] { "SomeNamespace.NuclearBomb", "SomeNamespace.Knife" })
    };

var factory = new PlayerFactory();
foreach (var entry in config)
{
    var player = factory.Create(entry);
    player.Fire();
    player.Switch();
    player.Fire();
}
```

... you end up with following console log

> Player 'Player1' spawned 
>   Shotgun goes boom 
>   Stabbed teh sucker
>
> Player 'Player2' spawned 
>   Game over for everyone!!1 
>   Stabbed teh sucker

Answer (score 0):

When using the `Strategy` pattern, your design might look like
the UML diagrams below.

`Player1` delegates performing the `Fire()` operation to one of different weapon classes `Weapon1`, `Weapon2`,...

For further discussion please see the Strategy design pattern 
at http://w3sdesign.com.

[image]

```
public interface IWeapon
{
    void Fire();
}

public class Weapon1 : IWeapon
{
    ...
    void Fire()
    {
        //do actions of Weapon1
    }
    ...
}

public class Weapon2 : IWeapon
{
    ...
    void Fire()
    {
        //do actions of Weapon2
    }
    ...
}

public interface IPlayer
{
    void Update();
}

public class Player1 : IPlayer
{
    private IWeapon weapon;
    private IWeapon w1;
    private IWeapon w2;

    public Player1() 
    { 
        w1 = new  Weapon1();
        w2 = new  Weapon2();
        SetWeapon(w1);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(SWITCH_BTN_HELD)
        {
            if(weapon.equals(w1))  SetWeapon(w2);
            if(weapon.equals(w2))  SetWeapon(w1);
        }
        if(FIRE_BTN_HELD)
            weapon.Fire();
    }
    void SetWeapon(w)
    {
        weapon = w;
    }
}
```